# Does the CUDA compiler optimize the kernel based on the passed parameters?

Tags: compiler-construction, parameters, cuda, gpu, nvcc

I have a simple CUDA kernel that counts number of A's in a 1000 byte fragment 
of a very large string. The database is laid out so that memory accesses are 
coalesced. After returning from the kernel my main function copies the device 
array `results` to one on the host for further analysis.

```
__global__ void kernel(unsigned int jobs_todo, char* database, float* results ) {

  unsigned int id = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  float A = 0; int i; char ch;
  if(id < jobs_todo) {
    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i += 1){
     ch = database[jobs_todo*i + id];
     if(ch == 'A') A++;
   }
  results[id] = A;
}
```

The kernel runs fine. However, if I replace `results[id]=A` with something trivial like
`results[id]=10` or just comment out that line it runs much faster (10 times) and 
uses much fewer registers as given by `--ptxas-options=-v`. The kernel doesn't help
if I comment out that line. Does the CUDA compiler know this by looking at the passed
parameters? And so it chooses to do nothing?

Comment: If you change the code to results[id]=10, the compiler can determine at compile time that all preceeding computation represents "dead" code since the data in results[id] does not depend on A, and optimizes out the code that computes A. Thus the speedup you observe. I don't understand your other questions. Speaking generally, the compiler can optimize only based on information present at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is the result of compiler optimisation. The compile will prune "dead" code, that is code which doesn't directly result in a memory write. So your kernel

```
__global__ void kernel(unsigned int jobs_todo, char* database, float* results ) {

  unsigned int id = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  float A = 0; int i; char ch;
  if(id < jobs_todo) {
    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i += 1){
     ch = database[jobs_todo*i + id];
     if(ch == 'A') A++;
   }
   results[id]=10;
}
```

is effectively optimised to

```
__global__ void kernel(unsigned int jobs_todo, char* database, float* results ) {

  unsigned int id = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  results[id]=10;
}
```

Obviously the register footprint and execution time of the reduced code is much lower than your full code. You can confirm this by compiling your code to PTX and inspecting the emitted code.

Comment: I suspected this was happening but thought I'd check with the community. Thanks. I'm wondering though how the compiler keeps track of this. Sounds like quite a bit of housekeeping.

Comment: The compiler tracks data dependencies. Dead code elimination is a standard optimization that has been around "forever".